# How to display messages from Java buffer in JSF pages using Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I managed to create bundle with Primefaces. I want to create Java buffer and store there messages in FIFO order. When message is inserted into the buffer I want to display it into the JSF page. How I can do this with Primefaces?

I found example with Primefaces:

```
<h:form id="dccd">

    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />

    <p:panel header="Growl">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="Your Name: *" /> 
            <p:inputText value="#{bean.text}" required="true" label="Name"/>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{bean.save}" update="growl"/>
    </p:panel>

</h:form>
```

But this is working only when I call action listener.

Comment: Can I only use `p:push` in order to update the JSF page data or I have to use bought together?

Answer (score 3):

The reason your example only works when pushing the button is that you're updating the growl element.

You can do two things to make sure you keep getting new messages.

## Push

When using push the server pushes updates to the client when necessary. PrimeFaces has [some examples](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/index.jsf) that may help you realize push. I don't know if this works on all browsers though.

## Poll

Using polling the client periodically checks for updates (can generate a lot of network traffic). PrimeFaces has a poll element to make things easier, have a look at [the example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf). AFAIK it uses JavaScript so it should work on most modern browsers.